# WhatsApp Automation via Selenium

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, whatsapp

> I am automating `WhatsApp Web` with `selenium` browser automation using `java` and `Chrome` Below code is working :

```
    // Update a cell value

    DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();

    try
    {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("side")));

        System.out.println("Logged In....");

        for (int i = 0; i < SendToList.size(); i++)
        {
            String Number = SendToList.get(i);
            System.out.println("Opening link....");
            driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone="+Number);

            try
            {
                   Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
                   alert.accept();
                   System.out.println("Alert accepted....");
            }
            catch(NoAlertPresentException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Alert not detected....");
            }

            System.out.println("Proceeding ahead....");

            try
            {
                WebDriverWait await = new WebDriverWait(driver, 12);
                await.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("main")));
                System.out.println("In Message to...."+Number);

                driver.findElement(By.className("_2S1VP")).sendKeys(TextMessage);
                System.out.println("Message written....");

                driver.findElement(By.className("_2lkdt")).click();
                System.out.println("Message sent....");

                dtm.setValueAt("SENT", i, 3);

                Thread.sleep(4000);


            }
            catch (TimeoutException e)
            {
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='_1WZqU PNlAR']")).click();
                dtm.setValueAt("N/A", i, 3);
                System.out.println("Element not found...");
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) 
            {
                System.out.println("Could not sleep for 1 seconds or failed to send sms...");
            }
        }



    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < SendToList.size(); i++)
        {
            dtm.setValueAt("FAILED", i, 3);
        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "You must login within 60 seconds to WhatsApp...!!", "Alert", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
```

There are few things i wants to resolve are :

1. Most of the times even if logged in before 60 seconds and after sending 2 or 3 messages it throws you have to login within 60 seconds exception; which is not possible.. but yet happening..
2. I want to loop on login success only.. and also want to handle all exceptions in each loop.. and even a exception occurs it should continue next loop.. How exactly try catch exception should be placed...!!
3. Reloading the whole url again and again for sending each message takes a long time and bandwidth too .. How can i manage it with javascript without needing to reload it again and again.

Thanking you all

Comment: You consume the Exception in a catch block and never show it's real message. Moreover, you cover it with your custom message "must login within 60 seconds...". That way you won't know what exactly is happening, you need to have some log file where you can see the stacktrace of the exception. So simply log your error, analyze it and eventually, upload it to pastebin, so people can analyze it for you.

Comment: please cut your code. Extract juste What app selenium code in a java main. Is it more easy to reproduced on other computer and solve your problem.

Comment: @DevDio, Its TimeOutException of the driver...